# Compairing quasi-Poisson and negative binomial fits in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, negative-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

Are there any R functions that allow you to easily compare quasi-Poisson and negative binomial models to determine which error distribution is more appropriate for your data? Or - does this require writing a simulation from scratch?

Comment: Already asked here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378901/compairing-the-fit-of-quasi-poisson-and-negative-binomial-models