# Comparing the fit of quasi-Poisson and negative binomial models

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, fitting, model-comparison, quasi-likelihood

Is there any way to compare the fit of quasi-Poission and negative binomial models? If so, can it be done in R?

Comment: What is your motivation for comparing these models? Have a look at [Verhoef and Boveng, 2007, Ecology, 88(11)](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/07-0043.1).

See also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/comparison-negative-binomial-model-and-quasi-poisson) on comparing quasi-Poisson and negbin models (in R).

Comment: @Jessica B It is precisely the issues highlighted by Verhoef & Boveng 2007 that motivate me to compare these models. Without some way to compare them (such as through a simulation) there is not a good way to know which one is the best choice for your data, but, critically, they are likely to yield different results. So - they are not equivalent, but it is not clear how to choose between the two of them without running some kind of simulation. I have seen the post by 
Elena Spark and Gavin Simpson, but did not find that it answered my question. It may be that the answer is simply "no".

Comment: In your OP you ask for an answer to, "is this possible in R," rather than "is this a good idea and if so, why?". Perhaps the answer to the latter is already posted in stats exchange? If you find something, please share as I am curious the answer(s).

Comment: @Jessica Burnett It is not only a good idea to compare to find the best match for your data, but it is irresponsible not to (per Verhoef & Boveng 2007). Ironically, it seems (to me) like there is no good or clear way to do this. Hopefully, someone will correct me on that last point!

Comment: To be clear--my previous comment was to question whether your original question should include the term "in R"?

Comment: @JessicaBurnett Good point. I suppose that I do want to know that more generally, but, if the answer is yes, it would be ideal (for my purposes) to know whether it is a problem that someone has solved using R.